# User input of (string) data in linked list (C++)?

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, nodes, user-input

I am trying to make a code that will ask the user how many students they want to accept. After this, the user will input the names of the students.

The code I have made is:

```
void acceptingStudents()
{
    node *temp = NULL, *head = NULL, *run = NULL;
    int studentSize;
    char studentName;

    cout << "Number of students to be accepted: ";
    cin >> studentSize;

    for (int x = 1; x <= memberSize; x++)
   {
       cout << "Student's name: ";
       cin >> studentName;
       temp = new node();   
       temp->name = studentName;  
       temp->next = NULL;   
       temp -> prev = NULL; 
       if (head == NULL) 
       {
           head = temp;
       }
       else
       {
           run = head;
           while (run->next != NULL)
           {
               run = run->next;
           }
           temp -> prev = run; 
           run->next = temp;   
       }
   }
}

void main ()
{
    node *run = NULL;
    acceptingStudents();
    while (run != NULL)
   {
       printf("%d\n", run->name);
       run= run->next;
   }
    _getch();
}
```

I want the output for this to be something like

```
Number of students to be accepted: 3
Student's name: Allison
Student's name: Gerry
Student's name: Sam
```

but my code only outputs:

```
Number of students to be accepted: 3
Student's name: Allison
Student's name: Student's name:
```

How can I fix this and make sure that each student name that is inputted by the user becomes the data for each node? I am trying to make the nodes like this:

### [ Allison ] -> [Gerry] -> [Sam] -> NULL

On another note, I was able to make it work with numbers using this:

```
void addingNodes()
{
    node *temp = NULL, *head = NULL, *run = NULL;
    int studentSize;
    int studentNumber;

    cout << "Number of students to be accepted: ";
    cin >> studentSize;

    for (int x = 1; x <= studentSize; x++)
   {
       cout << "Student's class number: ";
       cin >> studentNumber;
       temp = new node();   
       temp-> value = studentNumber;  
       temp->next = NULL;   
       temp -> prev = NULL; 
       if (head == NULL) 
       {
           head = temp;
       }
       else
       {
           run = head;
           while (run->next != NULL)
           {
               run = run->next;
           }
           temp -> prev = run; 
           run->next = temp;   
       }
   }
}
```

It outputs:

```
Number of students to be accepted: 5
Student's class number: 27
Student's class number: 12
Student's class number: 4
Student's class number: 8
Student's class number: 30
```

My only problem with this is making it into a string instead of an int because I need the names and not the class numbers.

Comment: `void main()`? How old is your compiler?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel it is supposedly the newest version

Comment: `studentName` is a `char`, meaning 1 character. You should use `std::string`. If you're not allowed to, store the name in a `char` array.

Comment: @Confused.Student `main()` isn't `void` in any version of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a string or a character array to store a name.

`char studentName[SIZE];`
`std::string studentName;`

You cannot just assign a character array to another as well.

If you are using the `string` datatype, you can make use of the `assign` function.

```
std::string str;
str.assign("Hello World");
cout<<str;
```

Apart from this, your code for implementing a linked list seems to be slightly messy. Why do you have two pointers (next and prev) if you want to implement a singly linked list? Why not make a member function to add a node in the `node` class instead of doing it explicitly in the function?

Answer (score 0):

One issue i am observing is datatype of studentname is character, Make it string and it will work fine. The other issue is with this line "run != NULL". You are not updating the value run. Either pass run in fuctioon "acceptingStudents()" by reference or make the variable "run" global. In your given code you are mentioning it char